# DELPHI : EEncodingError - Invalid code page on windows xp embedded

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, codepages

Hi I have a application that works well on 
windows xp pro, windows Visa, windows 7

But when I run it on windows xp embedded it does not work
and gives the following error:

EEncodingError - Invalid code page

When the App was made with Delphi 2006 it work on windows XP embedded

**When the App is made with Delphi 2010 it does **not work on windows XP embedded****

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TEncoding.ASCII` property uses codepage 20127, which is not installed on XP Embedded by default.  You have to install it manually.  The `TEncoding` class does not exist in D2006.

Are you using Indy 10, by chance?  It uses `TEncoding.ASCII` by default for its string encodings.  This exact error has been known to occur when using Indy on XP Embedded.

Comment: Thanks - Enabling copepage 20127 - fixed the problem :)

Comment: For what it is worth, Indy 10 no longer relies on codepages for its ASCII support.  It implements its own `TIdASCIIEncoding` class internally.

Answer (score 0):

When does it crash?  On startup, or later?

That error is only found in one place, in the RTL at least. In SysUtils, `constructor TMBCSEncoding.Create(CodePage, MBToWCharFlags, WCharToMBFlags: Integer);`, which gets called by TEncoding to set up string encodings.

It takes the `CodePage` parameter and calls [GetCPInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318078%28VS.85%29.aspx) on it, and if it fails it raises this exception.  From the MSDN documentation and the exception message, what's probably going on is that your app is trying to use strings from a multibyte character set that's not supported by XP Embedded.  Are you doing anything unusual with strings or text work in foreign languages that use a different alphabet?

Comment: @Masson  it crash OnStartup, I am doing nothing unusual+ all the text is in english

Comment: @Charles: Weird.  Can you run BDS under XP Embedded?  This sounds like a job for Delphi's debugger.

Comment: @Charles - if it crashes before application.run, then it's likely something in the initialization section of a unit.  And you say that the text is English, ok. But is this an English XP Embedded? That probably matters too.

Comment: Also, try making a "hello, world" delphi project, and see if that runs on the embedded XP.  That should cut your troubleshooting in half.

Comment: The call made is GetCPInfo(FCodePage, LCPInfo), where LCPInfo is a variable of type TCPInfo, which is a record. The GetCPInfo function expects a pointer to where it can write its output for the second parameter. So I would have expected the call to be GetCPInfo(FCodePage, @LCPInfo)? Not sure though why it then doesn't fail on non-embedded XP?

Comment: @Marjan: It's a Delphi idiom.  When C code in a DLL expects a pointer to a value so it can modify it, as long as you don't need to pass it a **nil**, you can declare it as a **var** parameter instead of a pointer, and you end up with more readable code that way.  If you look at GetCPInfo's declaration in Windows.pas, that's exactly what it does here.

Comment: @Mason: Thanks for the explanation. I sometimes thinks Delphi shields us a little too much from the pointy things, but then again, I am glad it does...